# When taking Force Sensitive Emergent or Exile, when do you gain the force rating of 1?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

As the title says, when you take the Force Sensitive Emergent or Exile specialization when do you gain the force rating of 1? Is it upon unlocking the specialization which means you can dip into it and then immediately jump to the FaD specializations or do you need to spend XP until you unlock the Force Rating talent which increases your force rating by +1? (0 + 1 = 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When they take the specialization**

From the specialization  description:

> The Force Sensitive Exile specialization does not have any career skills associated with it. However, when a character purchases this specialization,  he automatically receives a Force rating of 1, if he did not already have it. If he already has a Force rating  of 1 or higher, it does not increase. - p.276 *Edge of the Empire* - The Force

The 5th Tier Force Rating Talent would add to whatever the PC's rating would be at the time that they took it (at least 1 as being force sensitive is a per-requisite to taking it).

Comment: Perfect. So then when someone takes the talent then they would have a force rating of 2.

Comment: Yeah, force powers are very iffy in general so it'd be a huge investment just to start using some of them if you had to work your way all the way down.

Comment: The biggest problem I'm having at the moment is some of my force users want to "close the door with the force" or "sense all the things" without buying the requisite force power because "the jedi in the movies and the books do it".

Comment: @Samuel refer them to the force power table, Force exiles aren't prequel jedi masters, they are people with a bit of power that are seeking to subtly use it if possible. Think of Luke trying to get the lightsaber to come to him in ESB.

Comment: Where is the force power table?

Comment: @samuel each individual power, like move, has its own upgrade table/map like the specializations. PCS can manipulate fine objects at a distance but it takes a lot of xp investment in control upgrades to do so.